# Problems with RubyGems

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm having some problems with ruby gems. I'm trying to install the gem `hitimes` although after trying to install it (even using sudo) I get this error: http://cl.ly/Hvlf.

Could it be that I already have it installed because I've tried a few times now. Is there a way to uninstall a gem?

The gem can be found [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/hitimes) on RubyGems.org and I've even tried to download the .gem file and install it that way but had no luck.

Comment: If you want our (unpaid, volunteer) help, it would be polite to at least show the error instead of making us hunt for it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I did include the error. It was too big to include in the text so I online, it can be found here: http://cl.ly/Hvlf.

Comment: do you have XCode installed? looks like you are missing header files ```/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21:19: error: AE/AE.h: No such file or directory```

Comment: @phoet yep, and the latest version from the Mac App Store, 4.3.3