# Error installing hitimes gem as part of Rails bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos

I am trying to install a Rails bundle that works on my 2009 iMac and 2012 MacBook Pro but does not work on my friend's 2011 MacBook Pro.  All of these systems are running Mavericks and have Xcode and the latest Command Line Tools installed (verified over and over).  Bundler reaches an error when installing hitimes and nokogiri; the hitimes error is here:

```
Installing hitimes (1.2.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling hitimes.c
compiling hitimes_instant_clock_gettime.c
compiling hitimes_instant_osx.c
compiling hitimes_instant_windows.c
compiling hitimes_interval.c
compiling hitimes_stats.c
linking shared-object hitimes/2.0/hitimes.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
ld: framework not found CoreServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hitimes.bundle] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/hitimes-1.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/hitimes-1.2.2/ext/hitimes/c/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing hitimes (1.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install hitimes -v '1.2.2' succeeds before bundling.
```

When we try, as it suggests, "gem install hitimes -v '1.2.2'", we get:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing hitimes:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling hitimes.c
compiling hitimes_instant_clock_gettime.c
compiling hitimes_instant_osx.c
compiling hitimes_instant_windows.c
compiling hitimes_interval.c
compiling hitimes_stats.c
linking shared-object hitimes/2.0/hitimes.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
ld: framework not found CoreServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hitimes.bundle] Error 1
```

To me, this looks like we still do not have Xcode or the Command Line Tools installed.  However, we have reinstalled both of these.  What might be the problem?

I have seen posts on a similar issue, but none that include a resolution.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394632/problems-with-rubygems) and [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193942).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself when we upgraded to Ruby 2.1.1.